# Stop drawable´s animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I want to do an animation with a drawables but I want stop this animation when the last drawable is shown. I have used this code:

```
        final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) muneco.getBackground();
        muneco.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if ( mailAnimation != null ) mailAnimation.start();


              }
        });
```

and my anim.xml is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot="false"
      >

     <item  android:drawable="@drawable/dieciocho" android:duration="50"/>
     <item  android:drawable="@drawable/diecisiete" android:duration="50"/>
     <item  android:drawable="@drawable/dieciseis" android:duration="50"/>
     <item  android:drawable="@drawable/quince" android:duration="50"/>
     <item  android:drawable="@drawable/catorce" android:duration="50"/>
     <item  android:drawable="@drawable/trece" android:duration="50"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Why don't you set `android:oneshot` to true? Then your drawable will be played once.

Comment: I did not know , many thanks

Comment: You can also do it with view.clearAnimation();